# "Selected" Button Animation/Style

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I was curious about how I could make **a normal button**, with a "selected" style or animation.
`<button> I'm a button </button>`

When you use **Radiobuttons**, you can see clearly that you have a selected style whenever you click on the button.
`<input type="radio">`

[image: Example]

Now is the question, is it possible to have a selected style or animation (Not a click/hover animation) for the last button that you clicked (Without obviously having to use radiobuttons/checkbox).

If so, how does one make this?

[JSFiddle if you want to use the code that I used in the GIF](https://jsfiddle.net/JulianDotExe/bq9vydpe/75/)

I haven't found a lot of articles about this, or maybe just haven't looked good enough, anyways, maybe you people know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Include the JS in your page.
2. In your HTML, similarly to what you would do by adding the `name` and `value` attributes to your `<input type="radio">`s you add the `data-name` and `data-value` attributes to the elements you wish to behave as `<input type="radio">`s. If you want one to be selected by default add the attribute/value `data-selected="true"` to it.
3. Target the selected elements in CSS with the `[data-radio-selected='true']` selector.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const radioGroups = {}

  document.querySelectorAll('[data-radio-name]').forEach( el => {
    const name = el.dataset.radioName;
    const value = el.dataset.radioValue;
    const selected = el.dataset.radioSelected === 'true';

    // Register radio
    radioGroups[name] = radioGroups[name] || {
      radios: [],
      selected: null
    };

    radioGroups[name].radios.push(el);

    if ( selected && radioGroups[name].selected == null ) {
      radioGroups[name].selected = value;
    }

    // attach listeners
    el.addEventListener('click', () => {
      radioGroups[name].radios.forEach( el => {
        el.dataset.radioSelected = 'false';
      })

      el.dataset.radioSelected = 'true';
      radioGroups[name].selected = value;
    })
  })
})
```

```css
[data-radio-selected='true'] {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button data-radio-name="animals" data-radio-value="pig">
  Pig
</button>
<button data-radio-name="animals" data-radio-value="cow">
  Cow
</button>
<button data-radio-name="animals" data-radio-value="chicken">
  Chicken
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer also did the trick and is even more helpful in my situation! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just toggle a class with an onclick event:

```
btnState = false;
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  btn.classList.toggle("selected");
  btnState = !btnState;
});
```

In the CSS add:

```
.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

And add an id="btn" to the button in the HTML.